# How to Check the radio button and bind the it to listview's IsSelected property simultaneously

Tags: wpf, listview, c#-4.0, radio-button

I have a listview which is created dynamically and I have bound the SelectedIndex and ItemsSource properties to my ViewModel. My template has a radio button and I have bound the IsChecked property to the listview's IsSelected property. Now I'm able to determine which item is selected which is good but in the UI, I'm not able to check the radio button. This is clearly a UI related issue. Any suggestions? My code is as follows:

```
<ListView Height="330" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex,Mode=TwoWay}" Name="idleTimeoutAppListView" ItemsSource="{Binding listViewEntries}" SelectionChanged="ItemSelected" Margin="15,15,15,0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
             <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="auto">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextProp,Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                        <RadioButton GroupName="radioButtonGroup" DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}}">
                            <RadioButton.LayoutTransform>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2"/>
                            </RadioButton.LayoutTransform>
                        </RadioButton>
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I just tested your XAML and it works fine. Remove the `SelectionChanged` event handler, whatever it does.

Comment: @HighCore: I removed SelectionChanged and I can see the radio button now. But When I open the view and out of 3 radio buttons if I want to check any 1. How do I do it without binding the radio button to a bool in the viewModel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed SelectionChanged event and bound the selecteditem event and it works fine now. But my listview item which is selected cannot be selected again